# Задание по Java, проблемы с Arrays

Tags: java, массивы, ооп

По учебе необходимо решить задание, в котором создается "магазин" с несколькими товарами, где пользователь может указывать количество товаров (оно обязательно больше нуля). У меня получилось практически все, но по заданию цену надо посчитать в отдельном классе. К моему удивлению, я столкнулся с проблемой - ума не приложу как правильно это осуществить

Вот мой существующий код -

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GoShopping {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        Shop shopping = new Shop();

        System.out.print("How many shampoos? ");
        shopping.buy("Shampoo", Integer.parseInt(inputReader.nextLine()));

        System.out.print("How many soaps? ");
        shopping.buy("Soap", Integer.parseInt(inputReader.nextLine()));

        System.out.print("How many towels? ");
        shopping.buy("Towel", Integer.parseInt(inputReader.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Total price: " + shopping.getTotalPrice());

    }
}

class Product {
    public String name;
    public int price;
    public int qty;

    public Product (String name, int price, int qty) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public void setQty (int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}

class Shop {
    private static ArrayList<Product> products;

    public Shop() {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products.add(new Product ("Shampoo, 10, 0));
        products.add(new Product ("Soap", 3, 0));
        products.add(new Product ("Towel", 25, 0));
    }

    public void buy(String name, int qty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {
            if (products.get(i).name == name)
                products.get(i).SetQty(qty);
            }
    }

    public int getTotalPrice () {

    // Здесь надо сделать калькуляцию
    }
```

Comment: А что не так с обычным подходом (псевдокод): `for (i=0; i<products.size();i++) result += products[i].price * products[i].qty` ?

Comment: В задании есть условие, что нужно использовать отдельный класс getTotalPrice(). Проблемы в том, чтобы посчитать общую цену внутри - нет, но вся заваруха идет именно из-за getTotalPrice()

Comment: По описанию в коде `getTotalPrice()` не класс, а метод класса `Shop`. А как всё-таки должно быть? (точная формулировка)

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, ошибка вышла. Вот точная цитата: Write the code for the method getTotalPrice() at the Shop Class

Comment: Несколько смутило, что вы создаете экземпляр магазина, а потом это магазин.покупает продукты. По мне правильнее будет, если  новый покупатель(магазина). покупает(шампуней, 5шт). и они у него складываются в Корзину. И уже в корзине посчитать getTotalPrice().

Comment: Согласен, все можно сделать гораздо проще, но я лишь следую заданным условиям. Сейчас все им соответствует, кроме калькуляции - с чеем и возникли проблемы

Answer (score 2):

> Write the code for the method getTotalPrice() at the Shop Class

Пройтись циклом и подсчитать:

```
public int getTotalPrice() {
    int total = 0;

    for (Product x : products) {
        total += x.price * x.qty;
    }

    return total;
}
```

С [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) можно и [через стримы](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) подсчитать. Будет примерно так:

```
public int getTotalPrice() {
    return products.stream().mapToInt(x -> x.price * x.qty).sum();
}
```

Стримы очень просто распараллеливаются, достачно заменить `stream` на `parallelStream`:

```
return products.parallelStream().mapToInt(x -> x.price * x.qty).sum();
```

Аналогом `.mapToInt(...).sum();` может быть `collect(Collectors.summingInt(...))`:

```
return products.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(x -> x.price * x.qty));
```

Comment: или products.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(x -> x.price * x.qty))